# jQuery: wait for function to complete to continue processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all.  I have, what appears to be, a trivial problem.  I have the following JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var r = GetResults();

    for(var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        // Do stuff with r
    }
});

function GetResults() {
   $.getJSON("/controller/method/", null, function(data) {
       return data;
   });
}
```

Due to the fact that I'm calling a method asynchronously, the script continues executing and when it encounters the for loop, `r` obviously isn't going to have a value yet.  My question is: when I have a method that is doing an asynchronous operation, and I'm dependent on the data it returns back in the main block, how do I halt execution until the data is returned?  Something like:

```
var r = GetResults(param, function() {

});
```

where the function is a callback function.  I cannot move the for loop processing into the callback function of the JSON request because I am reusing the functionality of GetResults several time throughout the page, unless I want to duplicate the code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

move your "do stuff with r" block into your $.getJSON callback.  you can't do stuff with r until it has been delivered, and the first opportunity you'll have to use r is in the callback... so do it then.

```
$(function() {
    var r = GetResults();  
});

function GetResults() {
   $.getJSON("/controller/method/", null, function(data) {
       for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           // Do stuff with data
       }
       return data;
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The reason I split GetResults out was that I am reusing that functionality several times throughout the page.  I should edit my post to state that.

Comment: if you need to do the same processing on data coming from multiple places, just replace your callback function with a named function and do the processing there.

$.getJSON("/controller/method/", null, processData(data));

function processData(d) { ... }

Answer (score 8):

I've run into something similar before. You'll have to run the ajax call synchronously.

Here is my working example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/services/GetResources",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{resourceFileName:"mapedit",culture:"' + $("#lang-name").val() + '"}',
    cache: true,
    async: false, // to set local variable
    success: function(data) {
        localizations = data.d;
    }
});
```

Comment: This certainly works, but it blocks the UI thread, doesn't it? (Perhaps that's acceptable, though it doesn't seem necessary given the information we have so far.)

Comment: Yes, it does block, but of course only for the duration of the request. I don't see any other way around it, given what you're looking for. I went down the same road and went the sync route.

Answer (score 7):

Ajax already gives you a callback, you are supposed to use it:

```
function dostuff( data ) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // Do stuff with data
    }
};
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.getJSON( "/controller/method/", null, dostuff );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
$(function() {
    PerformCall();        
});

function PerformCall() {
   $.getJSON("/controller/method/", null, function(data) {
       for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // Do stuff with data
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't block on an asynchronous operation...which is of course, the meaning of "asynchronous".

Instead, you need to change your code to use a callback to trigger the action based on the data returned from the `$.getJSON(...)` call. Something like the following should work:

```
$(function() {
  GetResults();
});

function GetResults() {
  $.getJSON("/controller/method/", null, function(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // Do stuff with data
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your updated requirements ...

> I cannot move the for loop processing
>   into the callback function of the JSON
>   request because I am reusing the
>   functionality of GetResults several
>   time throughout the page, unless I
>   want to duplicate the code. Any ideas?

... you could modify `GetResults()` to accept a function as a parameter, which you would then execute as your `$.getJSON` callback (air code warning):

```
$(function() {
    GetResults(function(data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // Do stuff with data
        }
    });
});

function GetResults(callback) {
   $.getJSON("/controller/method/", null, callback);
}
```

As you can see from the general tide of answers, you're best off not trying to fight the asynchronous jQuery programming model. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Either you make your function synchronous or you change the design of your code to support the asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 0):

Move the data processing into the callback:

```
$(function() {
    GetResults();
});

function GetResults() {
   $.getJSON("/controller/method/", null, function(data) {

       for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           // Do stuff with data
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: this wont work. your return statement will return from the callback, not from GetResults. This solution will never work as it does not use callbacks properly

Comment: @mkoryak Thanks. I've removed the return from the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a callback with parameters that should work nicely...

```
$(function() {
    GetResults(function(data) {
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // Do stuff with data
      }
    });

});

function GetResults(func) {
   $.getJSON("/controller/method/", null, func);
}
```