# Wait for one function to complete before continuing in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, loading

I'm working on a wordpress editor for my blog, and need to be able to make sure that the function doGET() is finished before I click the save button with javascript or jquery. The doGET function might take a tad of time as I'm in a country with incredible slow internet connection...

```
$('#xmlbutton').click(function() {

    doGET();

    document.getElementById("save-post").click();  

})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: wait for function to complete to continue processing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455870/jquery-wait-for-function-to-complete-to-continue-processing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put...

```
document.getElementById("save-post").click();
```

in the callback of `doGET()` since it's an asynchronous operation.

Since I don't have all your code I made a little example.

```
$('#xmlbutton').on('click', function(){
  $.get('/post/edit', {"id":"12"}, function(result){
    $('#save-post').trigger('click');
  })
});
```

PS: Instead of `$('#save-post').trigger('click');` you should probably do `$('#save-post-buttons-form').trigger('submit');`.